# Implementar la función devuelveMayores '

Tags: javascript

Implementar la función devuelveMayores, que recibe por parámetro una LinkedList con precios de productos de una determinada góndola de Henry Market, y un precio máximo a evaluar.

La función deberá recorrer la LinkedList recibida y retornar la CANTIDAD DE PRECIOS QUE SUPEREN el valor de precio máximo que se desea evaluar.

En caso de que ningún precio supere dicho valor, debe retornar en string "Sin precios"

La función debe retornar un valor numérico, que representa la CANTIDAD DE PRECIOS que superen el valor a evaluar.

En caso de que ningún precio supere dicho valor, debe retornar el string "Sin precios"

```
function devuelveMayores(lista, valor) {
        

    let contadorquesuperenelvalor=0;
      for(let i = 0 ; i<lista.length ; i++){
        if(lista[i]>valor){
        contadorquesuperenelvalor++;
        } 
      }
    if(contadorquesuperenelvalor>0){
    return contadorquesuperenelvalor;
    }
    else {
      return "Sin precios";
    }

  
  

}
```

Comment: Cual es tu pregunta?

Comment: La función debe retornar un valor numérico, que representa la CANTIDAD DE PRECIOS que superen el valor a evaluar. ...  mi consola recibe "sin precios"

Comment: yo quiero que cuando contadorquesuperenelvalor sea mayor a 0 me devuelva el valor de contadorquesuperenelvalor

Comment: Y Cómo recibes esa lista que es una linkedlist? Seguro que así la debes recorrer? Si la recorres mal, seguro que tu contador va a permanecer en cero... por favor ve a [edit] para añadir las respuestas a los comentarios y mejorar tu pregunta

Comment: si es una linkedlist , recibe por parámetro una LinkedList con precios
de productos de una determinada góndola del Market, y un precio máximo a evaluar.

Comment: como hago para que puedas responder con codigo?

Comment: claro es una lista enlazada la tengo que recorrer de otra manera

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y muéstranos cómo está estructurada la lista enlazada y por qué la estás recorriendo mal :) Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: me podes mostrar como harias vos ese codigo?

Comment: Pero tienes que compartir cual es la estructura de esa "LinkedList" para poder ayudarte con el error... porque así a simple vista el "si la linkedlist se recorre como un array" debería funcionarte... como dice el compañero @Alfabravo lo mas probable es que esa lista no se recorra así, por eso debes compartir el código de como está estructurada esa lista

Comment: listaPrecios1 = 5 => 10 => 8 => 7 => 14 => 20
//  devuelveMayores(listaPrecios1, 10) => 2
//  (2 precios (14 y 20) superan el valor a evaluar (10))

Comment: Pana, que edites la pregunta, por favor.